# hg status shows all files modified on OSX but not Windows

Tags: mercurial, vi

After editing a project with vi on my mac, I run

hg stat

Every file in the project is listed as modified. Then I run

hg diff --git

Only the files I modified output diff information

If I run hg stat on windows for the same project, only my modified files are listed.

NOTE:

- The project is being shared from my mac using NFS.
- This doesn't happen when editing sublime text.
- When I run hg diff --git it does not show that permissions have changed
- Mac Version is: Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.7.1+20130905)
- It appears to be after python files are compiled on windows

Answer (score 0):

> The project is being shared from my mac using NFS

It's always a **Very Bad Idea (tm)** (sharing this way instead of clones), especially between different OSes

Mac and Windows uses different (incompatible) EOL-style,it can be source of "all strings changed after commit" permanent headache - just because on another OS file have to be stored with another EOL

You *may have* EOL extension on Windows side (or changes style of EOL in SublimeText settings?). Anyway, compare "modified" files (old and new state) with **good** diff-tool, which can detect EOL-difference and change broken part of workflow

Comment: If I use diffmerge, it shows no differences. Also, no editing was done on any of the files in windows.